# How to resolve this Sass compiling error?

Tags: css, sass, gulp, node-modules, gulp-sass

So, when I start working, I do gulp watch so my changes automatically get compiled. Thing is, I often get an error and the code doesn't get compiled. What I usually do to quickly fix this up is, add a blank space and then remove it to save the file again. After that, it compiles like it should.

Here is my gulpfile.js.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'); 
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber'); 
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var replace = require('gulp-replace');

gulp.task('default', ['compileSass', 'watch']);

gulp.task('compileSass', function () {
    return gulp.src('./styles/main.scss')
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(autoprefixer({ browsers: ['> 0%']}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'))
        .pipe(cleanCSS())
        .pipe(rename('main.min.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('./styles/**/*.scss', ['compileSass']);
});
```

Here is the error I get.

```
C:\Users\stipe\Desktop\slicing-zavrsni-rad>gulp watch
[23:58:12] Using gulpfile ~\Desktop\slicing-zavrsni-rad\gulpfile.js
[23:58:12] Starting 'watch'...
[23:58:12] Finished 'watch' after 25 ms
[23:58:24] Finished 'compileSass' after 108 ms
[23:58:26] Starting 'compileSass'...
Error in plugin 'sass'
Message:
    styles\pages\module.scss
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: container.scss.
       Parent style sheet: C:/Users/stipe/Desktop/slicing-zavrsni-rad/styles/pages/module.scss
        on line 1 of styles/pages/module.scss
>> @import 'container.scss';
   ^

[23:58:26] Finished 'compileSass' after 14 ms
[23:58:28] Starting 'compileSass'...
[23:58:28] Finished 'compileSass' after 77ms
```

I tried reinstalling node.js, gulp and sass but it didn't fix the problem. It's driving me nuts, could someone please help?

Comment: Have you tried to delete your sass cache? It is a folder named `.sass-cache`, should be in your project root or in the same directory as your gulpfile.

Comment: It also says it may be "unreadable".  I would try with a new stripped down container.scss and see if you still have the same problems.  You also might try @import './container';    It shouldn't make a difference but an easy check.

Answer (score 1):

the error says that there's no **container.scss** file or it's unreachable and you're trying to import it, check typos for the file name or the path of the file.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you must check if the file `container.scss` exists and if it's in the same folder as the `module.scss` file.

Also keep in mind the following information:

> Notice we're using @import 'reset'; in the base.scss file. When you import a file you don't need to include the file extension .scss. Sass is smart and will figure it out for you.

Source: [Sass Basics](http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-5)

Comment: They both exist and they're both in the same folder. I tried removing the extension now and it still doesn't work.

I'm pretty confused because it compiles correctly two times, then it throws an error and after that it compiles again correctly five times. And the cycle repeats again, pretty weird.